# Is Sun Java is compulsory for doing android projects using eclipse in ubuntu ? I already installed OpenJDK

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, java

Is Sun Java is compulsory to build android projects using Eclipse IDE over Ubuntu 10.10 ?? I installed OpenJDK in my ubuntu system. Now i  have to remove all openJdk packages and have to download those sun java packages and to do this it takes me a lot of time. Is there any other solution ?

If it is possible to run with OpenJDK, what are the configurations need to set in eclipse ?

OpenJDK version:
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.10.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan:  I think that's what he's asking...

Answer (score 3):

[Android's official page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) says that the Oracle JDK is required. OpenJDK may work, but I would spend the time and remove a potential source of issues. It's not that big of a deal, and you don't have to remove the existing jdk. Just install the official one in a different directory and point Eclipse to that.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: How to point my Eclipse to OpenJDK/Oracle Java, because i am new to eclipse ?

Comment: It depends on the version, see here for an example: http://matsim.org/docs/devguide/eclipse/jdk

Answer (score 1):

The OpenJDK should work just fine. What makes you think you need the Sun JDK?

Comment: If you see that official page, at the last of page, it is:

For Linux users

If you encounter this error when installing the ADT Plugin for Eclipse:
An error occurred during provisioning.
Cannot connect to keystore.
JKS
...then your development machine lacks a suitable Java VM. Installing Sun Java 6 will resolve this issue and you can then reinstall the ADT Plugin.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html